# How do you select from list in a GUI tab?

Tags: powershell

I have a Listbox in a tab which lists from a database.
The problem is how to use the selected text.

Normally I would use `$result = $form.ShowDialog()` but I have tried `$result = $tab.ShowDialog()` and get the error “method failed invocation because [System.Windows.Forms.TabPage] does not contain ‘ShowDialog’”.

Is there a way to select from a listbox in a tab?

Comment: Are you also getting an error when showing the form? Can you edit your question and show the code? A TabPage  should be shown with SelectedTab.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no real difference between selecting a Listbox item from a form or a Tab. In the code below, after the controls are added onto the form and tabcontrol, clicking `OK` shows the selected item from the listbox (from Tab1) to the other tab (Tab2).

Selecting the item from the Listbox is done via `$listBox.SelectedItem`.

```
Function selectButton_Click()
{
    $item = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $Resultlabel.Text = "The selected item is: $item"
    $TabControl.SelectedTab = $Tab2
}


Function closeButton_Click()
{

    $form.Close()
}

function myForm
{

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = 'Continents'
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,250)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

    $selectButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $selectButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,150)
    $selectButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $selectButton.Text = 'OK'

    $selectButton.Add_Click({selectButton_Click})


 # Create tabControl and Tabs
    $TabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
    $Tab1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
    $Tab1.Text = 'Tab1'
    $Tab2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
    $Tab2.Text = 'Tab2'

  #Tab Control 

     $tabControl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
     $tabControl.Name = "tabControl"
     $tabControl.Size= New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,200)
     $form.Controls.Add($tabControl)

     $tabControl.Controls.Add($Tab1)
     $tabControl.Controls.Add($Tab2)

     $Tab1.Controls.Add($selectButton)

     $closeButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
     $closeButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,150)
     $closeButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
     $closeButton.Text = 'Close'
     $closeButton.Add_Click({closeButton_Click})

     $Tab1.Controls.Add($closeButton)

     $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
     $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
     $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
     $label.Text = 'Select a continent:'
     $Tab1.Controls.Add($label)


     $Resultlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
     $Resultlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
     $Resultlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
     $Resultlabel.Text = 'The selected item is:'
     $Tab2.Controls.Add($Resultlabel)


     $listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
     $listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
     $listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
     $listBox.Height = 80

     [void] $listBox.Items.Add('Africa')
     [void] $listBox.Items.Add('America')
     [void] $listBox.Items.Add('Asia')
     [void] $listBox.Items.Add('Europe')
     [void] $listBox.Items.Add('Oceania')

     $Tab1.Controls.Add($listBox)

     $form.ShowDialog()


}

myForm
```